# go get fails to download dependency due to "undefined" compiler errors

Tags: go

I have a module dependency that gets downloaded for running tests. But the command fails with incorrect errors. though definitions are found in the library, compiler complains it is `undefined`

go.mod:

```
github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33 v33.0.9
```

command that fails

```
go test ./...
go: downloading nhooyr.io/websocket v1.8.6
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.5.1
go: downloading github.com/klauspost/compress v1.13.6
# github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:18:54: undefined: RegisteredSmartTransport
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:39:43: undefined: Remote
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:39:62: undefined: Transport
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:39:74: undefined: SmartSubtransport
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:70:13: undefined: Transport
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:74:59: undefined: SmartServiceAction
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/delta_string.go:28:9: undefined: Delta
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/difflinetype_string.go:36:9: undefined: DiffLineType
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/errorclass_string.go:52:9: undefined: ErrorClass
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/errorcode_string.go:55:9: undefined: ErrorCode
/go/pkg/mod/github.com/libgit2/git2go/v33@v33.0.9/http.go:74:59: too many errors
```

Comment: it might be related to CGO did you try disabling the CGO and running the test? try doing  `export CGO_ENABLED=0`

Comment: these errors appeared on my local machine too when i disabled CGO. will investigate further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

git2go is a wrapper around libgit2, a C library. It requires enabling CGO `CGO_ENABLED=1` for compilation.

ensure `GOOS` and `GOARCH` variables are set to appropriate values depending on the OS and the CPU architecture.